# Can you write depth values to a depth buffer in a compute shader? (Vulkan GLSLS)

Tags: c++, graphics, glsl, vulkan

I have a raytracer that I need to use in combination with traditional triangle projection techniques, I need to make the raytraced image be able to occlude projected triangles. The easiest way would be to write depth values directly to a depth buffer.

Apparently imageStore can only work with color images. Is there a mechanism I can use? The only alternative is to store depth in a color image and then make a dummy shader that sets the depth in a fragment shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listoptimaltilingformats.php

It would appear that most implementations don't allow using depth images as storage images. I suggest creating an extra image and copying/blitting it to the depth image.